# Avoid jvmOptions in Tomcat's service.bat and use JAVA_OPTS which is set in catalina.bat

Tags: windows-services, tomcat8, jvm-arguments, catalina

I want to bypass setting of JVMOptions in service.bat while creating tomcat service and use JAVA_OPTS set in catalina.bat starting service.

This is to avoid setting same jvm arguments twice as we can start using service or startup.bat

Is this possible

Thanks,
kusumat

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can configure Tomcat Server on Windows OS either by service or standalone.

If you configure tomcat as a service , it will never call `catalina.bat` during start-up.
Same way, if you use standalone mode it uses only `catalina.bat` (won't use `service.bat`)

Decide the mode you are going to use and set the JVM options based on the mode.